# Disable keydown until function is complete

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to disable all keycodes until the `next()` function is complete.

I tried using `return false` but it didn't work.

```
nextDown = {};
    $(document).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == '39'){
            if (nextDown['39'] == null) {
                next();
                nextDown['39'] = true;
            }
        } 
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        nextDown[event.keyCode] = null;
    });
```

Is there a way bind false against the `keydown` then after the function is complete unbind?

Comment: How do you define that *next()* is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about declare a variable to do so. Does the following code solve your problem?

```
nextDown = {};
var _lock = false;
    $(document).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == '39'){
            if (!_lock && nextDown['39'] == null) {
                _lock = true;
                next();
                nextDown['39'] = true;
            }
        } 
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        nextDown[event.keyCode] = null;     
    });


    function next() {
        ...
        _lock = false;
    }
```

If not, please, provide a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to accomplish this. First create a global variable and set it to 0. Then have the cont set to 1 before next() and back to 0 after next() is complete. This will allow you to create if statements where `cont == 1` would stop your other functions and `cont == 0` would allow them to run.

```
var cont =  0;

    $(document).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == '39' && cont == 0){
            if (nextDown['39'] == null) {
                cont = 1;
                next();
                cont = 0;
                nextDown['39'] = true;
            }
        } 
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if (cont == 0) {
            nextDown[event.keyCode] = null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but instead of using an integer variable, you should use a boolean for readability.  Also, I would rename the variable to 'DisableKeyStrokes' or something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a callback to do what you want.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/